# Mercurial clone operation works, but I don't have write access

Tags: mercurial, clone, ubuntu-9.10, slicehost

Somewhere I did something silly.

I was deploying my Rails app via cloning the Mercurial repo down onto my Ubuntu server. It worked the first time, and then...well, I made a small change on my dev machine, pushed the changes to the repo, and then deleted the copy on the Ubuntu server and re-cloned from the repo.

The clone operation (the second, and third, and 'n' times) works without error, but I don't have write access to the files that were cloned.

When I try to startup my mongrel - it can't create the /tmp folder, and because of no write access, fails to start the Rails app.

Comment: UPDATE: I "fixed" it by running a chown command on the app root, but I still feel like I did something wrong, or just not the right way. I guess I'll stick with this until I find the real answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed through work around stated in comment above.